# Guy has a dream with premonitions that come true

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen this old movie (black and white, Arabic language, Egyptian accent) back in 1998 (but the movie must have been made before 1970)

The plot begins when a little boy sees his mother in a dream and she does not recognize him. She tells him: her daughter (his sister) died in a train accident. And that he will die at the age of 24 or something like that. And one other thing about their future.

He wakes up and realizes that his mother is dead a long time ago.

Over the time, the things his mother told him in the dream come true, except for the last one.. Where he is supposed to die at the age 24.. You see, he becomes a doctor and at his 24th birthday he is sad and waiting for the moment that he will die (since the other two premonitions before were accurate).

Then an emergency occurs and he decides to operate on the patient (which turns out to be a pregnant lady in labor)...

We later find out that : had he remained in that room where he was depressed, he would have died due to a fire.
But since he decided to be a reason for some other life to happen, he was given a second chance.. or something like that.

I know this site does not focus on movies in Arabic, but I thought maybe the movie I saw is a rip-off some other movie that you might have seen or heard about. In my case, I could not find the name of the Arabic movie, nor the names of any actors in it. The only way I can reach it is if I can link it to another movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after the B&W Egyptian thriller [Saut min el madi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0342962/combined) (AKA Voice from the Past) from 1957. From an online site (sorry for not attaching a link, it looked kinda shaky):

> This film revolves around a boy whose dead mother appears to him in his dreams and who experiences visions into the future of tragic events. He tries to keep his sister from marrying an army officer after a premonition that they’ll die, but unable to stop them, they both pass away in a car accident. As he progresses through life he is plagued by the thought that he will die at age 25 as he saw in an earlier dream, and he must live his life until that point when he can see if these premonitions will all come true and whether his own life will end.

Can't find any pics or videos, I'm afraid (it proves very hard), but I think it's what you're after.
**EDIT:** System Down found a page on an Egyptian website with the film's synopsis, poster and actors; it can be found [here](http://www.elcinema.com/work/wk1000453/).

Comment: Here's a link to it from elcinema (an Arabic IMDb-like site) http://www.elcinema.com/work/wk1000453/

Comment: Thank you so much, this site proves to be greater every day

Comment: May i ask: how come you get lucky searching and finding movies while you are clearly not Arabian? I have been searching for this movie since i had access to the internet, with no luck.

Comment: Well, I often know the movie or at least know *of* it, but yeah, not in this case... I just fed the specifics in your (nicely detailed) question into IMDb and only 3 movies popped out. They had no synopses, but one seemed to be about a journey to the moon and the second was a comedy. The third was your film. :)